# alternating two lines in a div

Tags: html, css

### i'm making a chords app and i need the following pattern:

`Am    F          G           Am     Ab           Gdim       A#`

Hello this is are lyrics just for demonstration hey hey hello

### **to turn into this**:

`Am    F          G           Am`

Hello this is are lyrics just

`Ab           Gdim       A#`

for demonstration hey hey hello

### when reaching end of div

i saw a similar question in android, and they suggested using a linear layout to achieve this.

edit: as requested, this is the code i currently have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="line">hello this is my first line, it has a lot of words and will wrap to the next line</div>
    <div class="line">A        B  C            D       E       F  G          H             I J      K L</div>  
</div>
```

there is no css right now, the classes are empty

Edit: the break should happen at the end of the div, when the word is supposed to wrap, so that the two lines are acting as one line at the break (like in the example)

Comment: Can you please share with us the current html and css code that you have, in order for us to help you? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell us when do you want the break to happen? Detail more your request if possible

Comment: The question is unclear and requires too much guesswork.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it was clear. I added more information

Comment: the question is clear, he's just asking how could he make those elements to have different padding from each other....

Comment: @Lvcaa not exactly, i just want the lines that were "broken" from the line wraps to show up like this: start of line 1, start of line 2, end of line 1, end of line 2

Answer (score 0):

If you know the amount of characters you want per-line, you can achieve this using javascript: https://codepen.io/schart/pen/OJwdexj

In the solution above, what I'm doing is

- Getting the text content of both of the lines
- Splitting them both up into chunks of a given length of characters
- Creating new HTML using these lists to map them into pairs of lines.

Here is the Javascript, in case the link ever expires:

```
  const charsPerLine = 38;

  const computeLine = (line) => {
    const regexp = `.{1,${charsPerLine}}`
    const newLines = line.match(new RegExp(regexp, "g"));
    return newLines;
  }

  const computeLines = () => {
    const [text, notes] = [...document.querySelectorAll(".line-container > .line")].map((line) => line.textContent);
    const [textLines, notesLines] = [text, notes].map((line) => computeLine(line));
    const maxLines = Math.max(textLines.length, notesLines.length);
    
    let newHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < maxLines; i++) {
      newHTML += `<div class="line">${textLines[i] ?? ""}</div>`;
      newHTML += `<div class="line">${notesLines[i] ?? ""}</div>`;
    }
    document.querySelector(".line-container").innerHTML = newHTML;
  }

  computeLines();
```

This solution assumes that you have all the text in the first `.line` and all the notes in the second `.line`

Comment: I want this to be dynamic, and use the screen size as reference. Im looking for a solution that can be achieved without js

Comment: You could debounce a window resize listener and achieve that using some calculations, but yeah. If you're set on using that format of markup then I don't think there's a pure CSS alternative here.